# Fork function in Unix

Tags: c, fork

I created a simple fork program in c

```
printf("first");
fork();
printf("second");
```

I learnt that fork function creates a child process that executes from the next instruction which should be like

```
firstsecondsecond
```

but the output i got is

```
firstsecondfirstsecond
```

Am i wrong?

Comment: try to `fflush` stdout before forking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) is *buffered*. More specifically it's by default (when output is to a terminal) line-buffered, meaning that the buffer is flushed on newline.

Now what happens here is that the first `printf` call writes `"first"` to the output buffer, but it's not flushed. Then you fork, which creates an exact duplicate of the process, including the `stdout` buffer. Then both processes prints `"second"`.

After that, presumably, both processes ends which causes `stdout` to be flushed and closed. This flushes the contents of the buffers in both processes, which will contain the exact same data, leading to the output you get.

If you explicitly flush the buffer before calling `fork` (for example by printing a newline or calling `fflush(stdout)`) the behavior should be as you expect.